# Combinatoral Injections Proof?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $I(n,k)$ be the number of injections from an $n$-set to a $k$-set.

Prove using a Combinatorial Proof that:

$$I(n+1,k) = (k-n)I(n,k)$$

for $k \ge n$.

Workings:

Proof:

LHS counts the injections of a set with $n+1$ elements into a set with $k$ elements

RHS counts Injections of a set of $n$ elements into a set of $k$ elements  and then allows for the fact $k$ is greater than $n$.

I don't believe I am right. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t see any way to give a good hint here, so I’m going to explain the combinatorial argument in detail as an example instead.

Following a standard convention, I’ll write $[n]$ for the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$; this is a handy set with $n$ elements. Suppose that I want to build an injection from $[n+1]$ to $[k]$. One way to do it is by starting with an injection $f$ from $[n]$ to $[k]$ and then extending $f$ to $[n+1]$ by deciding what $f(n+1)$ should be. The injection $f$ uses up $n$ of the elements of $[k]$, i.e., the ones that are $f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(n)$; $f(n+1)$ has to be one of the other $k-n$ elements, or it won’t be an injection. Thus, each of the $I(n,k)$ injections $f$ from $[n]$ to $[k]$ can be extended to $k-n$ different injections from $[n+1]$ to $[k]$. That accounts for $(k-n)I(n,k)$ different injections from $[n+1]$ to $[k]$. And if you think about it a little, you’ll see that *every* injection from $[n+1]$ can be obtained in that way, so $I(n+1,k)=(k-n)I(n,k)$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ineedanewnames: You’re welcome.